# Is it ok to use non-annotated classes (beans) in spring framework?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot project. Some of the classes I am using it in the 'spring' way, meaning that they are annotated by "@Service", "@Repository", "@Autowired". At the same time, I have lots of classes, which are only used in the normal Java way, meaning that there are no any Spring annotations, and they are created in the standard way of constructing an object in a constructor.

For example, one of the non-annotated classes is:

```
public class GenericTree<T>
{
    private GenericTreeNode<T> root;

    public GenericTree ()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public GenericTreeNode<T> getRoot ()
    {
        return this.root;
    }

    public void setRoot (GenericTreeNode<T> root)
    {
        this.root = root;
    }
   ...
}
```

Is it OK or normal to have a mixure of classes with or without Spring annotations? Probably, I could convert all non-annotated classes into annotated classes by using Spring's annotation markers. Does that really benefit or is it necessary?

BTW, my application's main logic and functions are not web-centric, although they are created as a Spring project. The reason I created in Spring is I want to provide a restful service for my interface so that I can easily test in browser in development, and others can use it with Restful service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is ok.

Keep in mind that annotations are not Spring exclusive. Annotations were introduced in Java 5 and they are just meta data for your Java code. This meta data can be useful at:

- Compile time
- Build time
- Runtime

You can even create your own custom annotations and annotate your code with them.

Spring framework comes with some annotations and each one of them has its purpose, but that doesn't mean you have to annotate all your classes with Spring annotations when you are using this framework.

When you annotate your classes as Spring Beans, they become part of the Spring Application Context, thus making them available to be injected with the @Autowired annotation (Spring framework is based on the dependency injection design pattern). But Spring annotations have other implications too, I cannot go into the detail of each one of them but for example, you have to consider that the default scope of annotations like @Bean, @Component, @Controller, @Repository, @Service is Singleton. So whenever you annotate a class with one of these annotations and you don't define a scope, what you get is a singleton class shared all over your application. Other scopes are:

- singleton
- prototype
- request
- session
- application
- websocket

Taking in consideration your `GenericTree` class, does it make sense to annotate an abstract data structure class as a Spring Bean? Probably not.

So yes, when you develop an application based on Spring framework the normal thing is to have a mixture of Spring annotated classes and regular POJO's.

I recommend you to read the Spring framework documentation, learn what dependency injection is and the purpose and implications of the most used Spring annotations.